How to use a Gradle plugin from a version catalog without applying it
If you use a Gradle version catalog to add a plugin, the plugin will be applied when the code looks like this:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.springframework.boot)
}

How can the plugin be added from the version catalog without applying it?

Append a call to apply(false), like this:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.springframework.boot).apply(false)
}

